# How to fetch the User profile picture in linkedin using id?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Is there any direct url to grab the image using the linkedin id or name.

Here i am getting the image but it is thumbnail [link](http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_5R4EH7AXk7EbawaQF0ezHDhw6fZBaSOQbx2zHDrnJWubAdd6djHQQSkZHG4eSE0Ek4VNFEabeAMw)
 Is it possible to get the actual image?

Comment: you want to fetch img url of linkedin and you taged in twitter

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? Have you reviewed the documentation? Have you reviewed the data being returned by the relevant API calls?

Answer (score 0):

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the content and then use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to store the image in server.

if that doesn't work use [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)